# offline online events in service worker

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am making an extension on the manifest version 3, and Service Worker is used there, how do I listen to events that the user is online or offline? Events like online or offline don't work in Service Worker. navigator.onLine works but I need events

Here's what I tried

```
self.addEventListener('online', function () {
    console.log('online')
})
self.addEventListener('offline', function () {
    console.log('offline')
})
```

Comment: Sounds like yet another bug in ManifestV3. The workaround is to do it inside an [offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/) document.